# preg_match: get div-s which don't contain div(s)

Tags: php, regex

I can't figure out how get only those 'div'-s (with content) which don't contain other div(s).

For example:

```
<div id='first'>
    ...
    <div id='second'> 
        ...
    </div> 
</div> 
<div id='third'> 
    ...
</div>
```

And I need only the 'second' and 'third' divs' content, opening and closing tags because they don't include other divs.

I tried this pattern: `~(<div id='[a-z].+')(.*?)(</div>)~s` 
But it's not ok.

I hope I'am clear... thank you in advance!!

Comment: another one parsing html with regexp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not a Nazi about using rexex to extract HTML, this problem is a lot easier with xpath and the DOM.

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divs = $xpath->query("//div[not(div)]");
```

I didn't test that code. But the key part is the not operator that finds all divs without a div childnode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, it must be easier with xpath but I really would like to know how to do with regexp if it's possible of course.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible. Maybe, but it'd be very complicated. What's wrong with xpath, they're very easy to use in PHP, just search around SO for all the information you need.

Comment: Nothing wrong, I just was interested in if it's possible to do it with regexp. So thank you again. I'm using xpath!